# How do I join on "most recent" records?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I've got two tables in a SQL Server 2000 database joined by a parent child relationship.  In the child database, the unique key is made up of the parent id and the datestamp.

I'm needing to do a join on these tables such that only the most recent entry for each child is joined.

Can anyone give me any hints how I can go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the most optimized way I've found to do this.  I tested it against several structures and this way had the lowest IO compared to other approaches.

This sample would get the last revision to an article

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ARTICLES AS t
    --Join the the most recent history entries
        INNER JOIN  REVISION lastHis ON t.ID = lastHis.FK_ID
        --limits to the last history in the WHERE statement
            LEFT JOIN REVISION his2 on lastHis.FK_ID = his2.FK_ID and lastHis.CREATED_TIME < his2.CREATED_TIME
WHERE his2.ID is null
```

Comment: Thank you, that totally sorted it for me.

Comment: I'm glad I could pass it along.

Comment: Mighty inefficient O(N^2). Check out the ROW_NUMBER solution for O(N) complexity.

Comment: Can't use Row_Number() in a SQL Server 2000 database, so that doesn't help.

Comment: @wqw You might want to check out the tags before deducting points.

Comment: Ooops, my bad! Of course you can't. This is still mighty inefficient and quickly turns into a mess if you "order by" more than one column `(lastHis.CREATED_TIME < his2.CREATED_TIME OR lastHis.CREATED_TIME = his2.CREATED_TIME AND lastHis.SecondColumn < his2.SecondColumn)` or more than one base table. I would personally use a `SELECT TOP 1` sub-query anytime, just did it on a million table (actually a couple of JOINed tables). Can't believe no one mentioned it as a reply already...

Answer (score 6):

If you had a table which just contained the most recent entry for each parent, and the parent's id, then it would be easy, right?

You can make a table like that by joining the child table on itself, taking only the maximum datestamp for each parent id. Something like this (your SQL dialect may vary):

```
   SELECT t1.*
     FROM child AS t1
LEFT JOIN child AS t2
       ON (t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id and t1.datestamp < t2.datestamp)
    WHERE t2.datestamp IS NULL
```

That gets you all of the rows in the child table for which no higher timestamp exists, for that parent id. You can use that table in a subquery to join to:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM parent
     JOIN ( SELECT t1.*
              FROM child AS t1
         LEFT JOIN child AS t2
                ON (t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id and t1.datestamp < t2.datestamp)
             WHERE t2.datestamp IS NULL ) AS most_recent_children
       ON (parent.id = most_recent_children.parent_id
```

or join the parent table directly into it:

```
   SELECT parent.*, t1.*
     FROM parent
     JOIN child AS t1
       ON (parent.id = child.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN child AS t2
       ON (t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id and t1.datestamp < t2.datestamp)
    WHERE t2.datestamp IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this query as a basis 
Note that the CTE definition is not part of query-So the solution is simple

```
use test;
with parent as (
select 123 pid union all select 567 union all
select 125 union all 
select 789),
child as(
select 123 pid,CAST('1/12/2010' as DATE) stdt union all
select 123 ,CAST('1/15/2010' AS DATE) union all
select 567 ,CAST('5/12/2010' AS DATE) union all
select 567 ,CAST('6/15/2010' AS DATE) union all
select 125 ,CAST('4/15/2010' AS DATE) 
)
select pid,stdt from(
select a.pid,b.stdt,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.pid order by b.stdt desc) selector
from parent as a
left outer join child as b
on a.pid=b.pid) as x
where x.selector=1
```

Comment: again, can't use this in SQL Server 2000